# Converting ASPX Application to ASP.NET Core MVC: Is there a tool or recommended approach for a direct conversion?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, migration, upgrade

I currently have an ASPX application, and I'm looking to migrate it to ASP.NET Core MVC. I'm wondering if there is a recommended tool or a straightforward approach for this conversion process.

What I've Tried: I have tried using Microsoft.NET.UpgradeAssistant to facilitate the conversion process. While the tool does create an MVC application, it seems to establish a proxy connection to the existing ASPX application rather than converting the entire application to MVC.

Expectation: I was expecting Microsoft.NET.UpgradeAssistant to perform a complete conversion of the ASPX application to ASP.NET Core MVC, including the UI and code-behind files.

Comment: No - going from Webforms to ASP.NET Core MVC is a **major** rewrite - the underlying platform and the whole web approach changes fundamentally - no easy and straight-forward "conversion" for this - neither manually nor by a tool.

Comment: Well, you stated asp.net, but are you talking about MVC project or a web forms project? Edit-- ah, yes, given a proxy,  then yes this must have been a webforms project.  So yes, you have to rewrite to a MVC project. So no automated conversation exists due to vast different architecture. The proxy idea gets you up and running and then you convert over time. Conversation tools work for MVC projects to MVC .net core, but not for webforms projects

Comment: there is no tool but you could follow this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/web_forms?view=aspnetcore-8.0 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38065940/best-practise-to-migrate-web-forms-to-asp-net-core-mvc